# Is it possible to compile Java 1.5 source Web Applications to 1.4?

Tags: java, web-applications, java1.4, java-5

I tried compiling my webapplication  with `javac – source 1.5 – target 1.4` I end up with the error:
javac: source release 1.5 requires target release 1.5

Since I’m using generics and other features; when I try compiling with `–source 1.4` I end up with the errors:

```
(use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
(use -source 5 or higher to enable for-each loops)
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
```

I need to deploy to a box with Java 1.4 installed; of which I have no control of, so upgrades are out of the question.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [Retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yes, I have several fairly large applications for which I use retroweaver.  So far, it seems to work wonderfully.

Comment: Hey it works nicely. I've even modified Netbeans build scripts so that Retroweaver would be automatically weaving code. Awesome.